# Upstart script vs. command-line: why this difference in behavior?

Tags: tomcat, scripting, shell, upstart

I'm trying to set up Tomcat to start with upstart.  I find the following works:

```
  description "Tomcat Server"

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  setuid tomcat

  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
  env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34

  script
    chdir $CATALINA_HOME
    exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
  end script
```

But if I remove the `chdir`, tomcat starts, but with plenty of `FileNotFound` exceptions when my `.wars` load.  (That is: the `.wars` themselves do load but they throw exceptions on load.)

Note this behavior is **different** from what I see when I invoke `catalina.sh` from the command line.  Invoking from the command line, I can run `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/catalina.sh run`  *from any directory* (without chdiring) and everything's fine.

**So why is the `chdir` necessary in my upstart script?**  (How is the upstart environment different from my command-line environment?)

---

Example of the errors I'm seeing w/ upstart when I don't chdir:

```
Feb 22, 2013 3:00:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive my-war.war
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-war.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

Comment: ...It's probably changing the current working directory to `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34`, and if you remove that it will quite obviously get "file not found" errors as it's trying to run the script in some other directory.

Comment: As I tried to ask in my question though:  how come I can execute (on the command line) `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/catalina.sh run` from anywhere, without chdiring, and things work fine?  (Things only break when running from **upstart** without chdir).

Comment: Are you asking out of pure curiosity? Because the chdir is obviously there to change the current working directory, and while I can't answer why it's required it certainly makes sense.

Comment: I would like to understand why upstart breaks  without it, given that **on the command-line I can run `catalina.sh` via absolute path from anywhere**. This is for my own understanding (since I'm obviously missing something about the environment upstart presents).

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but you should use `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/startup.sh` (without chdir). That script in turn execs **catalina.sh**.

Comment: @Nils:  execs *catalina.sh* but exits immediately -- which prevents upstart from being able to **stop** the job later (unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion).

Comment: Do what @Nils said. Do not run catalina.sh directly. startup.sh setups a whole bunch of tomcat variables for you. Also if you run this as some sort of cron script, the environment the script runs in may not have all the environment variables are set. You may have inadvertently set this in your own login for example.

Comment: can you paste the output of `env` command here.

Comment: I am not familiar with upstart - but "respawn" is propably another problem in this context. To determine if tomcat is still up and running I usually access a typical URL of a deployed application and check if the content contains an expected keyword. Tomcat7 is still a pain with regards to automated startup/monitoring - even when using classical init-scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a write permission issue. User tomcat is not allowed to create a log file to a location where it tries to create them. The location it tries to create log files in differs depending on how you start tomcat.

This piece from from your log caught my attention:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-war.log (Permission denied)
>      at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)

It says that the user (tomcat) is not allowed to create the file my-war.log. Here are the different scenarios:

**Upstart with chdir**

Upstart first chdirs to $CATALINA_HOME. User tomcat is allowed to create files there. So everything works.

**Upstart without chdir**

Upstart runs as root, so the default directory is /. User tomcat is not allowed to create files there. So you get permission denied errors.

**Running tomcat from your home dir**

Now you run tomcat as yourself from your home dir. You have write permission to you own directory. So everything works again.

Comment: Bingo!  I **thought** I was able to successfully run this from the command line, but it turns out I could only run it from the command line when starting in places where the tomcat user has write access. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to an upstart version with `setuid` support, but this is what I would do in your case.

It looks like an environment discrepancy issue. Most likely an environment variable that is not set when running from upstart. Could it be that `setuid` does not set `$USER` or `$HOME`?

Therefore, I would recommend that you compare the environments. A easy, simple way would be to modify your init script like this and restart the job.

```
  script
    env > /tmp/env-upstart.log
    chdir $CATALINA_HOME
    exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
  end script
```

Then also run `env > /tmp/env-console.log` when you normally would start it from the console (if you are using `sudo`, then do it with `sudo env`).

Then compare the two `/tmp/env-upstart.log` and `/tmp/env-console.log` files (sort them and open them with `vimdiff`) and it should be easy to find which variable in `env-upstart` is missing from the other file (or is set to something that you would not expect).

### Update 1

And if you are still getting errors, I would check the following:

- **User permissions**: effective/real user ids might be differing. Compare the output of `id`, `id -r -u`, `id -r -g`, `id -r -G`, `id -u`, `id -g`, and `id -G` in both cases.
- **Process limits**: It could be that your upstart scripts have stricter limits. Try putting an `ulimit -a` to compare.
- **Shell oddness**: Not likely, but upstart uses `sh` while your user's shell is most likely `bash` or `zsh`. Try running the successful command from `sh`.
- **Debug the script**: If you are still really, really stuck, run `catalina.sh` in debug mode. This is as easy as running it from upstart like this:

  ```
  exec /bin/sh -x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run 2>/tmp/catalina-upstart.log
  ```

  Then you can compare the two debug logs and maybe spot where the two scripts did something different.

Comment: Comparing env output, the `upstart` environment was missing several variables (including `$USER` and `$HOME`).  But even adding  *all* of these environment variables to upstart does not reproduce the success of a command-line call.

I added an example of the error (one of many) to the post above.

(+1 for the vimdiff recommendation, thanks)

Comment: Well, I updated my answer with more ideas. I hope some of them point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's about permission. But not related to Upstart.
This is because in 'catalina.sh start', i.e. in the 'start' part, the real command is:

```
  ...
  -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
  >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
```

Here the output log is fully assigned. While there is no "$CATALINA_OUT" in the RUN part. This will lead the writing permission problem mentioned above. Namely, if no specific output file path assigned, the output will go to either logs file or do that as your.war coded. These kinds of unclear log assignment will lead uncertain permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

To get a complete dump of all environmental elements between running your server on the command-line compared to running it under Upstart, try installing my procenv tool, running it in both environments and diffing the output files:

- https://launchpad.net/procenv/
- http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/procenv-and-process-environment.html

This is available in the ubuntu raring and debian sid archives (and FreeBSD).